# Auto Generate Unique column in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was using the primary key (`TicketID`) as an `identity` column which was auto incrementing on every time a ticket is generated. Everything was going smoothly and then I started seeing that my `TicketID` jumps from 5,6 to like 1007, 1008.

Upon googling, I found about this design-by in SQL Server 2012:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/743300/identity-column-jumps-by-seed-value

Now I want to custom create a column, which will auto increment just like identity column but does not jump and leave gaps (I don't want an `identity` column)

How should I do that? I think triggers are what I am looking for but as I have never used triggers before, I would really appreciate some help here.

OR should I use computed column?

Comment: Basically: you **should not** do that. Don't - don't even waste your time and effort on it. So the `IDENTITY` in SQL Server 2012 has some gaps - ***SO WHAT?!?!***

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2012, if you really want to "avoid" the gaps in `IDENTITY` - use a `SEQUENCE` and define the `NOCACHE` option, and insert those sequence values in a `ON INSERT` trigger. In that case, no values will be cached, no "gaps" can occur upon restart - **but be aware** that this in turn has negative impacts on your performance!

Comment: So, you want to force every transation that wants to insert into this table to be serialized until all preceding transactions have completed or rolled back just so that it can pick the correct next value to use? Also, you're using the word `bug` wrong. This was *designed in* behaviour.

Comment: Well I want my TicketID to be serial wise. My TicketID column is the Ticket # in my application. My application has a datagridview which will display all tickets. Its awkward to see such random TicketID. I don't want to skip 1000 number everytime sql server is restarted.

Comment: You'll find similar behaviour in every database system I can think of. The purpose of these systems was to provide a quick and easy way to uniquely identify rows. The fact that one of the ways to quickly and easily do this is to have a counter and increment it is why so many database systems offer just that. But these values should be treated as opaque blobs as far as everything outside of the database is concerned - you certainly shouldn't be showing them to your users.

Comment: So what is the solution for my problem? How do I generate Ticket Number which is auto incremented on every insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just solved my problem using a AFTER INSERT trigger.
Here it is what I did.

```
     ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tid2]
     ON [dbo].[tblPrac2]
     AFTER INSERT
     AS
     declare @nid int;

     set @nid = ( select MAX(TicketID) from [tblPrac2] );

     if(@nid is null)
     begin
         set @nid = 1;
     end
     else
         set @nid = @nid + 1;

update tblPrac2 set TicketID = @nid where ID in (select ID from inserted)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create you own autoincrement mechanism is a bad idea.

Look at SEQUENCE object http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

But if you still want to do this, **one possible solution is**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TicketNumber
(
    Number INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.TicketNumber(Number) VALUES(0)

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_GenerateTicketNumber
(
    @Number INT OUT
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Number INT 
    DECLARE @CurrentNumber INT

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        SELECT
            @CurrentNumber = Number
        FROM dbo.TicketNumber WITH(UPDLOCK)

        SET @Number = @CurrentNumber + 1

        UPDATE dbo.TicketNumber 
        SET Number = @Number

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

**The alternative implementation** of dbo.sp_GenerateTicketNumber **may be looks like**

```
DECLARE @number TABLE(number INT);

UPDATE dbo.TicketNumber
SET 
    [Number] = [Number] + 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.Number INTO @number;

SELECT * FROM @number
```

**And the solution you want, probably**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_RegisterTicket
(
    @PersonName varchar(255),
    @TicketNumber INT OUT
)
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRAN

        SELECT
            @TicketNumber = MAX(TicketId) + 1
        FROM dbo.Tickets WITH(UPDLOCK)

        INSERT INTO dbo.Tickets VALUES(@TicketNumber, @PersonName)

    COMMIT TRAN

END
```

Using example:

```
DECLARE @Number INT
EXEC dbo.sp_RegisterTicket 'Vasya', @Number OUT

SELECT @Number
```

Comment: Can you tell me why is it such a bad idea? I just require a simple auto-increment column.

Comment: SQL Server has a regular, well-established tools for this purpose.
They are optimal in terms of performance.

Comment: @user3331470 I posted several solutions of you problem in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unique identifier, I think.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx

But it takes more space of course.

Comment: i had the same idea at least you won't see it doesn't follow well :) A trigger is a bad idea for a so small problem, you will create performance issue and small chance of crash (it depends of your trigger of course). Why don't you recalculate a row_number every night if possible.

Comment: I want to generate a serial/sequential TicketID column. Using unique identifier will generate random unique numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate IDENTITY column to remain without gaps .
For implementing your requirement , you will have to use  a table with single column and row which stores the current maximum value of TicketID and a stored procedure to access this value , increase it by 1 if insertion takes place and subtract by one if deletion takes place.
Of course this will have impact on performance vs using IDENTITY column and ignoring the gaps.

Comment: Can I do this by a trigger? Like whenever there is an insert - trigger should fire, retrieve previous value of column and then increment it by 1?
Do I really need another table?